# VBA Excel Split a sheet every n column

Tags: vba, excel, split

I have a transposed table with two "header columns". The table stretches for too long to the right, and I want to be able to split this table over several sheets every "n" columns, while also copying the two header columns to every new sheet. All the examples I can find only split every "n" rows, whereas I want to split every "n" columns.

I find it difficult to explain this in plain text, so I'm attaching screenshots: In this example, the first sheet contains the original data and the subsequent sheets contains the intented result of the macro, where the sheet is split every two columns:

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub colsplit()
Dim wssrc As Worksheet
Dim wsdest As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wssrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
'getting No of columns
lcol = wssrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
On Error GoTo resetsettings
'getting User input to split count
col = InputBox("Enter Number of columns to split")
If IsNumeric(col) And col <> "" And col > 0 Then
desti = 1
For i = 3 To lcol
Set wsdest = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
wsdest.Name = "split" & desti
'copying header columns to new sheets
wssrc.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsdest.Cells(1, 1)
wssrc.Columns(2).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsdest.Cells(1, 2)
desti = desti + 1
x = 3
For j = i To (i + col - 1)
'Copying other columns to new sheet
wssrc.Columns(j).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsdest.Cells(1, x)
x = x + 1
Next j
i = i + col - 1
Next i
Else
End If
resetsettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This code will split the columns and paste them to new sheets.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!